# Can you add a class/id to a session in laravel?

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4

I'm creating a website with laravel and when a user edits their details it will access the controller update them and redirect to the 'edit' page using this

```
return Redirect::to('/member/editprofile')->with('message', 'Information Changed');
```

this part works fine, it redirects and sends the message which is printed out on the page with this

```
{{ Session::get('message') }}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to add a class to the session? I'm probably missing something completely obvious here and this is what I tried...

```
{{ Session::get('message', array("class" => "success")) }}
//added the class as you would with a HTML::link
```

any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this

```
<div class="success">{{ Session::get('message') }}</div>
```

In `Laravel-4`, the [Session::get](http://laravel.com/docs/session#session-usage) accepts two arguments :

```
$value = Session::get('key', 'default');
$value = Session::get('key', function() { return 'default'; });
```

Comment: brilliant, thanks man... don't know why I didn't even think of that!